# redux state selectors in top level reducer

Tags: javascript, redux

After watching the [new egghead course](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux) by Dan Abramov, I have question regarding the selectors that was mentioned.

The purpose of the selectors is to hide the details of the state tree from the components, so that it is easy to manage code later if tree changes.

If I understand it correctly, that means, the selectors called inside `mapStateToProps` should only be the ones that live in the top-level reducer. Because the `state` that is passed to `mapStateToProps` is the whole application state tree. If this is true, as the application grows, I can imagine it would become very difficult to manage the top level selectors.

Have I miss understood the concept here? or is this a valid concern?

**Edit**: trying to make my question clearer.

Say my whole state start with
`{ byIds, listByFilter }` and I have

```
export const getIsFetching = (state, filter) =>
  fromList.getIsFetching(state.listByFilter[filter]);
```

in my top level reducer `reducers/index.js`, and components would simply use `getIsFetching` passing the whole state to is, which is totally fine because it is the top level.

However, later on, I decided my whole app is going to contain a todo app and an counter app. So it make sense to put the current top level reducers into `reducers/todo.js`, and create a new top level reducers `reducers/index.js` like this:

```
combineReducers({
  todo: todoReducer,
  counter: counterReducer
})
```

at the point my state would be like

```
{
  todo: {
    byIds,
    listByFilter
  },
  counter: {
    // counter stuff
  }
}
```

components can no longer use the `getIsFetching` from `reducers/todo.js`, because the state in `getIsFetching` is now actually dealing with `state.todo`. So i have to in the top level reducer `reducers/index.js` export another selector like this:

```
export const getIsFetching = (state, filter) =>
  fromTodo.getIsFetching(state.todo);
```

only at this point, the component is able to use `getIsFetching` without worring about the state shape.

However, this raises my concern which is all the selectors directly used by components must live in the top-level reducer.

**Update 2**: essentially we are exporting selectors from the deepest level all the way up to the top-level reducers, while all the exports in the intermediate reducers are not using them, but they are there because the reducer knows the shape of the state at that level.

It is very much like passing `props` from parent all the way down to children, while the intermediate component aren't using `props`. We avoided this by `context`, or `connect`.

apologize for the poor English.

Answer (score 1):

So while `mapStateToProps` does take the entire state tree, it's up to you to return what you'd like from that state in order to render your component.

For instance, we can see he calls `getVisibleTodos` and passes in `state` (and `params` from the router), and gets back a list of filtered `todos`:

**components/VisibleTodoList.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, { params }) => ({
  todos: getVisibleTodos(state, params.filter || 'all'),
});
```

And by following the call, we can see that the store is utilizing `combineReducers` (albeit with a single reducer), as such, this necessitates that he pass the applicable portion of the state tree to the `todos` reducer, which is, of course, `state.todos`.

**reducer/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import todos, * as fromTodos from './todos';

const todoApp = combineReducers({
  todos,
});

export default todoApp;

export const getVisibleTodos = (state, filter) =>
  fromTodos.getVisibleTodos(state.todos, filter);
```

And while `getVisibleTodos` returns a list of `todos`, which by is a direct subset of the top-level `state.todos` (and equally named as such), I believe that's just for simplicity of the demonstration:

We could easily write another perhaps another component where there's a `mapStateToProps` similar to:

**components/NotTopLevel.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, { params }) => ({
  todoText: getSingleTodoText(state, params.todoId),
});
```

In this case, the `getSingleTodoText` still accepts full `state` (and an `id` from `params`), however it would only return the text of `todo`, not even the full object, or a list of top-level `todos`. So again, it's really up to you to decide what you want to pull out of the store and stuff into your components when rendering.

Comment: I have edited my question. I don't think i was really clear before. it is not the toplevel component I am concerned about, but the top-level reducers

Comment: @xiaofan2406 I re-read the question and am now more confused. If you completely change the shape of your store, then yes, of course those selectors will no longer be valid because the shape of the state completely changed. Not sure what this has to do with selectors though, if your state shape changes, refactoring must occur anyway.

Comment: yes, refactoring is a must. but it doesn't change the fact that we always need to export selectors up to the top-level reducer so that components can use selectors without know state shape

Comment: @xiaofan2406 I think I understand your concern, but who's say say you can't create a chain of `selectors` that progressively pass down a smaller chunk of state the deeper down into the state you go? Top level is obviously `todos` but you can absolutely have another selector if your `todos` state contains something _else_ you want to select/pluck from that obj. It's also not law that you have only 1 selector per reducer. Why not `getByIdsFromTodos(state)`, `getListByFilterFromTodos(state)`. All up to you? Just build to pull what you need.

Comment: For example, in Dan's example, his selector is `getVisibleTodos`. That seems pretty specific. What about hidden todos? Or really anything else that's related to a todo, but completely unrelated to its visability. He's most likely craft just another selector.

Comment: creating a chain of selectors is my concern. because at the end, the components are actually only directly calling the top-level selectors only.

Comment: @xiaofan2406 Then craft a selector that gets _exactly_ what you need, deep from the tree and entitle it something descriptive. I mean, that's why it's called a `selector`. Select what you need. See my last comment above. Dan's selector ONLY gets todos based on filter. You think he's piping all future requests thru that same selector? No, creating new ones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114076/discussion-between-xiaofan2406-and-lux).

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this issue (and also had a hard time explaining it...). My solution for compartmentalization this follows from how `redux-forms` handles it.

Essentially the problem boils down to one issue - where is the reducer bound to? In `redux-forms` they assume you set it at `form` (though you can change this) in the global state.

Because you've assumed this, you can now write your module's selectors to accept the `globalState` and return a selector as follows: `(globalState) => globalState.form.someInnerAttribute` or whatever you want.

To make it even more extensible you can create an internal variable to track where the state is bound to in the global state tree and also an internal function that's like `getStateFromGlobalState = (globalState) => globalState[boundLocation]` and uses that to get the inner state tree. Then you can change this variable programatically if you decide to bind your state to a different spot in the global state tree.

This way when you export your module's selectors and use them in mapStateToProps, they can accept the global state. If you make any changes to where the where the reducer is bound, then you only have to change that one internal function.

IMO, this is better than rewriting every nested selector in the top level. That is hard to scale/maintain and requires a lot of boilerplate code. This keeps the reducer/selector module contained to itself. The only thing it needs to know is where the reducer is bound to.

By the way - you can do this for some deeply nested states where you wouldn't necessarily be referring about this from `globalState` but rather some upper level node on the state tree. Though if you have a super nested state it may make more sense to write the selector from a upper state's POV.

Comment: Noticed someone downvoted my answer. Would appreciate feedback please.